# Foreign Key of Foreign Key Field in Django

Tags: python, django-models

I have a model that looks like this

```
# models.py
from django.db import models


class Level_0(models.Model):
    Kode = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=False, blank=False, default="")

class Level_1(models.Model):
    Kode = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=False, blank=False, default="")
    Level_0= models.ForeignKey(Level_0, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Level_2(models.Model):
    Kode = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=False, blank=False, default="")
    Level_1 = models.ForeignKey(Level_1, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # Level_0 = ????????????

    # how do I create a connection to Level_0?
```

What I want to have is a field in `Level_2` that automatically connects to `Level_0` through `Level_1`. How do I add that field in my `Level_2` model?

Answer (score 0):

It is already indirectly related to Level_0. 
To access Level_0 corresponding you go through Level_1

Comment: I know it's related, but how do I add the field in ```Level_2```?